# Loading multiple streams in StringBuilder, one stream after the other

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to Dart Streams, and having a hard time figuring this out.

Basically, I have a stream for file download, then another stream for file processing. The file download stream can only be initialized after the file processing stream, because it depends on the file downloaded.

I need to display a progress widget going from 0 to 100%, and then again from 0 to 100%.

I tried using rxDart concatWith, to merge the streams, but it's not working. The ConnectionState.done is called on the first stream, and it doesn't listen to the other one. I am also not sure if this is the right way to go about it.

If I tried to do set the new stream in the builder, I would get this error:

> setState() or markNeedsBuild() called during build.

```
builder: (context, snapshot) {
      print(snapshot.connectionState);

      if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
        setState(() {
          stream =
              Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (i) => _source2[i]).take(_source2.length); // New Stream
        });
      }
```

What is a good approach for doing this?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve my problem by adding

```
WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_){
```

in the builder.

Here is a simple example that outputs two streams, one after another:

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new _MyAppState();
  }
}

class _MyAppState extends State<MyApp> {
  var stream; // state variable

  List<String> _source = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'];
  List<String> _source2 = ['g', 'h', 'i'];

  var _count = 0;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // stream = newStream(); // initial stream

    stream = Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (i) => _source[i]).take(_source.length);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    var streamBuilder = StreamBuilder(
        initialData: "0",
        stream: stream,
        builder: (context, snapshot) {
          print(snapshot.connectionState);

          if (snapshot.connectionState == ConnectionState.done) {
            _count++;
            if (_count < 2) {
              WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
                setState(() {
                  stream = Stream.periodic(Duration(seconds: 1), (i) => _source2[i])
                      .take(_source2.length);
                });
              });
            }
          }

          if (snapshot.hasData) {
            print(snapshot.data);
            return new Text(snapshot.data);
          } else {
            return new Text('no data');
          }
        });
    return MaterialApp(
        title: 'Trial',
        home: Scaffold(
            appBar: AppBar(title: Text('Stream builder')),
            body: Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                streamBuilder,
              ],
            )));
  }
}
```